# Wire format for OpenRasta array bindings (urlencoded and multipart/formdata)

Tags: openrasta

The wire format for binding arrays and dictionaries in OpenRasta seems to be ":index" like this:

```
class X
{
  public int[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

which serializes to (with two array items 5 and 12):

```
Data:0=5&Data:1=12
```

Is it possible to change this format to:

```
Data[0]=5&Data[1]=12
```

Thanks, Jørn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and replace the IPathManager with a custom one that supports that format. Alternatively, feel free to add support for that format too and send a pull request to openrasta-core.